# Specifying number of threads using XGBoost.train

Tags: xgboost, parallel, processing

When using the `xgboost.train()` function, all the threads are used. I would like to use a specific amount. Unfortunately, this function does not accept the parameters `nthread` nor `n_jobs`. How can I control the number of threads being used?

Thanks.

// Edit

It seems that I found a solution. In contrast with the method, how one provides the nthread (or n_jobs) parameter to XGBClassifier of XGBRegressor, by adding this parameter directly to the brackets as `xgb.XGBRegressor(nthread=n)` then as indicated on [xgboost document](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/xgboost/release_0.81/xgboost.pdf) (page 46), I added an additional parameter `parameters["nthread"] = number_of_threads` to the parameters (a dictionary) I am using. After testing with different numbers, the number of threads being used reported in htop was the same as the `number_of_threads` parameter provided. ***Can anyone confirm this to be the right method?***

Answer (score 1):

Using `xgb.train` function, you can set `nthread` in `params`.

```
xgb.train({'nthread': 3}, dtrain)
```

---

In the xgboost [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#global-configuration), afaict, there is no clear way how to set the `nthread` parameter. Some global params are set by xgb.set_config and some are not, like `nthread`.

But when I walk through their [test script](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/4224c08cacceba3f83f90e387c07aa6205a83bfa/tests/python/test_openmp.py#L23), I found `nthread` is set by `params` in `xgb.train`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the number of threads by nthread parameter in XGBClassifier or XGBRegressor

```
import time
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import xgboost as xgb
num_threads = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,16,32,64]
for n in num_threads:
    start = time.time()
    model = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror',nthread=n)
    model.fit(X, y)
    elapsed = time.time() - start
    print(n, round(elapsed,3))
    results.append(elapsed)
```

The output after execution of this code is

```
    1 0.059
    2 0.071
    3 0.063
    4 0.094
    5 0.075
    6 0.078
    8 0.09
    16 0.099
    32 0.157
    64 0.235
```

Comment: I think that XGBRegressor is only a wrapper of xgboost.train. Isn't there a way to specify the nthread or n_jobs for train() function? At the moment when running the code, it automatically uses all the available threads

Answer (score 0):

`libxgboost.so` as of version XGBoost-1.5.2 uses OMP for parallelization.

There is no option to set the number of threads used for prediction using XGBoost API, unfortunately, `nthreads` `DMatrix` argument has no effect.

Set environment variable [`OMP_THREAD_LIMIT`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse58.html#x297-20700006.10) to the maximum number of threads OMP can use. E.g. `export OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1` causes the following messages:

```
OMP: Warning #96: Cannot form a team with 32 threads, using 1 instead.
OMP: Hint Consider unsetting KMP_DEVICE_THREAD_LIMIT (KMP_ALL_THREADS), KMP_TEAMS_THREAD_LIMIT, and OMP_THREAD_LIMIT (if any are set).
```

In Python add these lines before other imports:

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_THREAD_LIMIT"] = "1"
```